# Cloud Functions, Firestore trigger, recursive delete not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Currently, I`m trying to delete all the nested hirachy datas when some documents deleted using Firestore Trigger

and my code and error code are below

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp({   
}
);


exports.firestore_delete_trigger_test = functions.firestore
  .document('collection1/{docs1}/collection2/{docs2}')
  .onDelete(async (change: any, context: any) => {     
    
    const path = change.path;

    await firebase_tools.firestore
      .delete(path, {
        project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
        recursive: true,
        yes: true,
        token: functions.config().fb.token
      });

    return {
      path: path
    };

  });
```

and the Error code is below

```
FirebaseError: Must specify a path.
    at Object.reject (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/utils.js:122:27)
```

why it shows error code? I do not want "callable functions" because of security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever use `any` when writing in TypeScript as you essentially "switch off" TypeScript and lose valuable type information such as why your code isn't working.

If you use the following lines, the type of `change` (which should be `snapshot`) and `context` are automatically set as [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html) and [`EventContext`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext) respectively as defined by the [`onDelete`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_.documentbuilder#ondelete) method.

```js
exports.firestore_delete_trigger_test = functions.firestore
  .document('collection1/{docs1}/collection2/{docs2}')
  .onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {

  });
```

**Note:** A `QueryDocumentSnapshot` is like a regular `DocumentSnapshot`, but it is guaranteed to exist (`snap.exists` always returns `true` and `snap.data()` will never return `undefined`).

Now that the type is restored to `snapshot`, you'll see that you can't read a property called `path` from it as it's not set. In your current code, `path` will just be set to `undefined`, which leads to the error saying you need to specify a path.

```js
const path = snapshot.path; // ✖ Property 'path' does not exist on type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'. ts(2339)
```

This is because `path` is a property of [`DocumentReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html). To get the snapshot's underlying `DocumentReference`, you access it's `ref` property.

```js
const path = snapshot.ref.path; // ✔
```

Next, in Node 10+ Cloud Functions, the list of [available environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#newer_runtimes) was changed and `process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT` was removed. To get the current project ID, you can use either

```js
const PROJECT_ID = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId;
```

or

```js
const defaultApp = admin.intializeApp();

const PROJECT_ID = defaultApp.options.projectId;
```

This then makes your (modernized) code:

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as firebase_tools from 'firebase-tools';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const PROJECT_ID = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId;

admin.initializeApp(); // config is automatically filled if left empty
                       // although it isn't needed here

export const firestore_delete_trigger_test = functions.firestore
  .document('collection1/{docs1}/collection2/{docs2}')
  .onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {     
    const path = snapshot.ref.path;

    await firebase_tools.firestore
      .delete(path, {
        project: PROJECT_ID,
        recursive: true,
        yes: true,
        token: functions.config().fb.token
      });

    return {
      path: path
    };
  });
```

Comment: wow.. so impressive answer thanks I will try this. and how do you get these info usually??

Comment: the original issue is solved and new error came up do you know why this happens?
FirebaseError: Failed to delete documents FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 401, Unknown Error
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/firestore/delete.js:251:28)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)

I tried this but still not solved

exports.firestore_delete_trigger_test= functions.runWith({
  timeoutSeconds: 540,
  memory: '2GB'
}).
  firestore
 .../

Comment: @rounpaleum [HTTP 401 Unauthorized](https://httpstatuses.com/401) suggests that the token you are using (`functions.config().fb.token`) is invalid. Update your `firebase-tools` on your system and generate a fresh token using `firebase login:ci`.